# windows phone c# check for valid url and replace foreach item in list

Tags: windows-phone-7, url, listbox

I am getting a list of objects in Windows Phone, and show them in a listbox with databinding.
some image urls are not valid, so after every object is added in the list, i run the following code to check and replace, if not valid

```
 private void CheckLinkUrl(Person p)
    {
            Uri filePath = new Uri(p.img_url);
            string correct = p.img_url;
            HttpWebRequest fileRequest = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(filePath);
            fileRequest.Method = "HEAD";
            fileRequest.BeginGetResponse(result =>
            {
                HttpWebRequest resultInfo = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
                HttpWebResponse response;
                try
                {
                    response = (HttpWebResponse)resultInfo.EndGetResponse(result);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    p.img_url = "http://somethingelse.com/image.jpg";

                }                    

            }, fileRequest);

    }
```

the problem is that it is **very** slow, it takes sometimes 2 minutes+ to load every image (although the UI remains responsive, and everything else is displayed immediately in the listbox, apart from the images)

am I doing something wrong? can i get it to run faster?

EDIT:
I tried using the imagefailed event and replace the link, no improvement at the speed of loading the pics

Comment: So you want to speed up the check itself or do you want to parallelize them? I suggest that you take Milan's instruction and set the default image which will preserve the space and give an initial visual cue. Later on you can easily replace images as they come.

Comment: yes, i found no other way, i'm following milan's advice, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have done to avoid this problem in my application is, I have loaded the items with a default Image, The image source is binded to a property in my result item of type `ImageSource`. By default it returns the default image. After processing or download completion the imagesource value changes to the new Image triggering the `NotifyPropertyChanged` event and hence it is automatically reflected on the UI. I hope it helps you.

Comment: there is no way to speed it up, what you suggested is a nice way to implement it, thank you :)

Comment: Since webClient- the downloader in this case can download only one item at a time, I believe this is the maximum speed which one can achieve in terms of downloading. But the next time if the image is in cache the retrieving will be faster.